Do default angular.json options override?
My simplified angular.json config is below. I am using Angular 16. I understand the default for outputHashing in Angular is none.
Given the below config, if I execute:
ng build --configuration=development

Will outputHashing: all be applied or will outputHashing: none be applied?
This article doesn't seem to clarify the position too clearly.
{
  "projects": {
    "myproject": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "outputHashing": "all"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media"
            },
            "development": {
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {},
        "extract-i18n": {},
        "test": {},
        "lint": {}
      }
    }
  }
}


"Default" means "if not specified". But in your example, it is specified to "all". So I see no reason why it should default to "none"

It is specified BUT is it specified for the development configuration in particular? I am not convinced based on the docs - its possible that the top level build options apply to all configurations except given configurations as opposed to overriding defaults - that's what I'm insure of and why I am asking this question

Think of the configuration as "overrides" to the config. And the "options" as your base options. The development config is just an empty object, so it does not override anything. So the base options come into play. Only if for a setting there is nothing in the base options and nothing in the overrides, the default value is used.

thanks @JSONDerulo I tested this and it works - please add an answer and I will accept

Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Consider the configurations as overrides to the config, and the options as your base options. The development config is just an empty object in your case, so it does not override anything. Here the base options come into play. Only if for a setting there is neither anything in the base options nor in the overrides, the default value is used. In your scenario, outputHashing: "all" will be used with the development configuration because it's defined in the base options and not overwritten.
Note: Unfortunately I do not have a reputable source to back this up, but this is how it works in my experience.

this is correct, I can verify this works
